# NLP Support for Gender decoding of words?

Tags: nlp, nltk, spacy

Is there any methods in NLP that can ascribe a gender indication to text? I'm not referring to identifying the gender of the author or tagging nouns like "Alice" as potentially feminine.

There is a tool https://capd.mit.edu/resources/gender-decoder/ which has a dictionary of masculine and feminine coded words from about 7 years ago https://github.com/Doteveryone/genderdecoder/blob/master/genderdecoder/wordlists.py
*feminine = "colab"*, *masculine = "assert"*

but has there been advancements in detecting or alternative methods of identifying potentially gendered text?